# List of analytic solutions to KL divergences of known distributions

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, optimization

Does anyone know a list of analytics solutions to KL divergences of commonly used distributions.

For example, 2 Normally Distributed Random Variables have a nicely formulated analytic solution.

Approximations should be fine too, I just need this for some optimization play where i don't have the computational resource to solve it through MC methods

Comment: If your distributions are both in the exponential family of distributions, then there is a general expression that can be derived - see this paper: https://web.archive.org/web/20190331194854/https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~nielsen/EntropyEF-ICIP2010.pdf

Comment: @Don This was wonderful! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, much information can be found by searching this site. For exponential families see [this paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20190331194854/https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~nielsen/EntropyEF-ICIP2010.pdf) (given in a comment above.)   For skew distributions [some information is here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Javier_Contreras-Reyes/publication/259515562_Asymptotic_form_of_the_Kullback-Leibler_divergence_for_multivariate_asymmetric_heavy-tailed_distributions/links/5b93c5354585153a53091cd8/Asymptotic-form-of-the-Kullback-Leibler-divergence-for-multivariate-asymmetric-heavy-tailed-distributions.pdf).  For Pareto distributions [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-8176-4487-3_13).  [Weibull distributions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257749354_Computing_the_Kullback-Leibler_Divergence_between_two_Weibull_Distributions). [Generalized gamma distributions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259899864_Computing_the_Kullback-Leibler_Divergence_between_two_Generalized_Gamma_Distributions).

[$=$1&isAllowed$=$y" rel="nofollow noreferrer">A somewhat related useful paper](https://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/20061/Lex2004Dec8UsefulFact.PDF?sequence<span class=).